# Issue Anguilla Framework in XPM

Tags: experience-manager, cme, gui-extensions

I'm developing an extension to give more functionality to Tridion and all works fine in the Content Manager, but I have tried to apply the same commands in XPM and the behavior is totally different.

I give you an example:

- CME: $display.getUri() returns *"tcm:XX-XXXX-64"*
- SiteEdit: $display.getUri() returns *undefined*

Do you know if exists a manual/documentation about the Anguilla Framework commands in XPM or any equivalence between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a similar commands that give us back the same result.
For example, the commands described in the post (return the tcm of the Page):

1. CME: `$display.getUri()` returns "tcm:XX-XXXX-64"
2. SiteEdit: `$display.getView().properties.pageSettings.PageID` returns "tcm:XX-XXXX-64"

Hope it helps.